# How to display form data in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I created one Play application using forms. The code is shown in below. My requirement is i will set the form value in my Application controller in the index method. This value i need to display in index.scala.html username field. How to display username value in the form.

## index.scala.html

```
@(login: model.com.ranga.Login)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center" style='background: #80c846;'>
        <div>Login Form</div>
        <hr />  
        <form method="post" action="@routes.Application.login()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username.."></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password.."></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.java

```
    package model.com.ranga;

    public class Login {

    public String username;
    public String password;

    public Login() {
        super();
    }

    public Login(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Login [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }   
}
```

Application.java

```
package controllers;

import model.com.ranga.Login;
import play.*;
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setUsername("Ranga");
        return ok(index.render(login));
    }

    public Result login() {
        Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();       
        Login login = loginForm.get();
        System.out.println(login);      
        return ok(index.render(login));
    }
}
```

index() method i am setting the username. this value i need to display in username field. how to set this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you chose not to create your model the way that play framework recommends creating your models? (Extending ebean model and letting it take care of all the boiler plate code)
Also this is one of the better documented parts of play framework. Take a look at the following links

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaForms
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers

To answer your question you want to pass a form object to your scala template that is bound to your login object. You can then pull the values from the form object.

Comment: With out using helper class i want to display the value.

Comment: <input type='text' name='username' value='here i want logic to get the login form username field value'></input>

Comment: In index.scala.html file i am getting the username field value while displaying like this @login. Now what i want is in username filed i want to display this value

Comment: Have you tried doing `<input type='text' name='username' value='@login.getUsername()'></input>` ?

Answer (score -1):

Answer is:

```
<input type='text' name='username' value='@login.getUsername()'></input>
```